# Why is this coming up null

Tags: javascript

I get a null error on the line this

```
document.getElementById("Attachment" + x).style.display = "none";
```

I really dont want to write this out 5 times.  The line does work if i do this.

```
document.getElementById("Attachment1").style.display = "none";
```

What am i missing here?  To keep this short i only included the loop where ther error is.

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{

  if(showHideArray[x] &gt; 0) 
  {
    document.getElementById("Attachment" + x).style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
        document.getElementById("Attachment" + x + "If").style.display = "none";
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have an element with ID `Attachment0`.

Comment: You were right and first to answer.  I did mot have an element with the id of Attachment0.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no element with the given id, this function returns null. So if I was you I would print out `document.getElementById("Attachment" + x).style.display = "none";`

Show us what it outputs. But one solution that will prob work is:

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{

  if(showHideArray[x] &gt; 0) 
  {
    var y = "Attachment" + x;
    document.getElementById(y).style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
        var z = "Attachment" + x + "If";
        document.getElementById(z).style.display = "none";
       }

}
```

I would try both those things.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access property `style` of `null`, this will throw an error. Check that the element exists before trying to access properties.

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("Attachment" + x + (showHideArray[x] > 0 ? "If" : "" ) );

    if( elem ) {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```